# Creating a subdomain with Google Cloud + CloudFlare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I have a domain bar.com on CloudFlare that is linked to a site hosted on Google Cloud. I can create a new A record on CloudFlare for a subdomain "foo", but how do I map that to bar.com/foo on Google Cloud?

I'm not sure if this question makes sense. Basically, I have a site that is hosted on standard server which I am moving to Google Cloud. On the standard server, I have CPanel which handles creation of subdomains (of which are added to CloudFlare's DNS). I'm not sure how this process is replicated on Google Cloud.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's basically to manually create a  entry. I was confused a little because I am using the Bitnami LAMP deployment.

In case this will help somebody in the future, if you're using Bitnami's LAMP, this is how you create subdomain(s)

Open the file `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` and add the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.bar.com
    ServerAdmin foo@bar.com

    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/foo"
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/foo">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

where `foo` is the subdomain. Then restart Apache `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

If you are using CloudFlare, you will need to add an A entry into your DNS, with `foo` as the name, and your Bitnami/Google Cloud deployment's IP. You may leave the status as bypass (grey cloud) or active (orange cloud), it doesn't matter.

Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 12):

First of all, you need to create another *Google Cloud Storage (GCS)* bucket to host your subdomain.

- Go to your GCS dashboard.
- Create a new bucket with name as your full subdomain url: **foo.bar.com**
- GCS will ask for you to verify you are the owner of that domain. If you already verified **bar.com**, you don't need to do anything else, otherwise follow this [**tutorial**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification).
- [Upload your files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#uploading_your_sites_files) to bucket.
- Make your bucket [public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).
- Finally, configure your [bucket website settings](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages).

Now, we can proceed to CloudFlare.

---

- Go to your CloudFlare dashboard.
- Open the DNS settings of your domain: **bar.com**
- Add a new record with this settings:

  > - **Type:** CNAME
  > - **Name:** foo (your subdomain)
  > - **Value:** c.storage.googleapis.com (default DNS address of GCS)
  > - **TTL:** Automatic TTL (or anything else, doesn't matter)
- Wait a few minutes, then open up your subdomain url.
- *Voilà! Hope this helps.*

Answer (score 1):

So you can create subdomains so you have: `bar.foo.com` but you can't create a DNS record for `foo.com/bar`. Enter CloudFlare, in CloudFlare you can set-up a page rule to redirect `foo.com/bar` to `bar.foo.com`.

You need to ensure `foo.com` is routed through CloudFlare and in DNS settings the cloud is orange. Then you need to make sure the DNS record for `bar.foo.com` is pointing to Google's servers instead of your cPanel.

Have fun!

Comment: Hi!

I think you misunderstood my question. What I mean is I'm trying to move my site (including subdomains) from VPS (with CPanel) to Google Cloud completely. The root domain is already on Google Cloud and working, but I don't know how to map the subdomains without CPanel.

I don't think the solution lies on CloudFlare though I might be wrong. I tried your forwarding method. All it does is show the content of bar.com with the URL foo.bar.com.