# How to install ssl certificate on subdomain in google cloud platform

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, subdomain

Can anyone help me to install SSL certificate on sub-domain that host on google cloud platform. I'm create  wordpress website(https://demo.com) using bitnami on google cloud platform and purchase ssl certificate and install it on google cloud platform.

And also i'm successfully creating sub-domain(http://sub.demo.com) on google cloud platform on same instance. But currently facing issue is how to install SSL certificate on subdomain(http://sub.demo.com).

My problem is,

1) How to install ssl to sub-domain on gcp? I'm creating sub-domain to refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33129772/10340666

2) And i'm created sub-domain on same instance that main domain is host. That means i'm use same VM instance for main domain and sub-domain. And i'm already install ssl on main domain. But this ssl is not install on sub-domain.

My main concern is how to install ssl on sub-domain that using same VM instance on gcp. If i'm i'm using different ssl then is problem occur?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) No it is not.

Comment: whats topic or not.

Comment: Please can you add more information about a) how you are trying to install certificate and b) the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Since Sub Domains are created in the bitnami.conf config file, You can generate Self-managed SSL certificates For Bitnami. You can follow the [Bitnami Generate And Install A Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate For A Bitnami Application documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/), to generate and configure the  Self-managed SSL certificates for sub domains.

By using the command below, you can generate the certificates for multiple domains/sub domains which are installed in the GCP VM.

```
sudo lego --email="YOUR-EMAIL" --domains="Your-Domains" --domains="Subdomains" --domains="Subdomains"  --path="/etc/lego" run
```

Then we link the new SSL certificates and configure the web server.

Comment: But letsencrypt  sale valid for only 3 moths.

Comment: Finally i'm install SSL on sub-domain. I'm purchase ssl and install manually from ssh. And change .htaccess file to work.